# Define a function digits_stars().... I cant seem to execute it correctly

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to define a function which has as input an integer number, and outputs the range of numbers before as a string with stars (*) between the digits:

```
print(digits_stars(3))
> 0*1*2*3*
```

My solution so far is doesn't work..

```
def digits_stars(n):
    ans = 0
    for i in range(n):
        ans = str(i) + "*"
    return str(ans)
```

This however outputs

```
2*
```

Comment: Two errors.  1) ans should be initialized to a string (not 0)--i.e. ans = "".  2) in your for loop have:  ans += ans + str(i) + "*".  Your current code keeps overwriting ans.

Comment: I tried this but somehow I seem to still be getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
def digit_stars(n):
    ans = "0*"
    for i in range(n):
        ans += str(i+1) + "*"
    return ans
```

Note that we start with 0* so the code also works for a zero input

Comment: Good catch on starting with `0*`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make ans a string
2. Include the old ans when updating ans

```
def digit_stars(n):
     ans = ""
     for i in range(n):
             ans = ans + str(i) + "*"
     return ans
```

How I would naturally do it.

```
def digit_stars(n):
    return "".join([f"{i}*" for i in range(n)])
```

Comment: I tried doing fixing my ans to ans = "" and adjusted my for loop to ans = ans + str(i) + "*"  but I am getting the same result

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes I do want that final '*'